# Creating CSS Transition for JS "onclick" Event Between HTML Pages

Tags: html, jquery, css, onclick, css-transitions

I'm working on a site that has 2 "sides", a technical and social. I want to add a button to change between the "sides" (i.e. if you are on the social "contact" page and press a button it takes you to the technical "contact" page).

I have the format working (for contact, for instance, I have two files, tec-contact.html and soc-contact.html, and a button that has the property onclick="transitionToPage('soc-contact.html')" or onclick="transitionToPage('tec-contact.html')" respectively). This switches the pages without a problem.

What I would like, though, is to animate it so it performs a 180 degree spin around the Y-Axis (showing both pages as it turns). At present I can only use a fade (with body {opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s;
}.

It's built on Bootstrap 4 and has jQuery 3.

Any suggestions or input would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are, apparently, a number of libraries dedication to this very task; including Barba, Animsition, and SmoothState.

I went with SmoothState.

https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/